# Website not scrolling vertically

Tags: css, html

My my website is not scrolling. This is the site https://www.wohooo.net/

It was scrolling before and then suddenly stopped. I am unable to troubleshoot it extensively because I created it with Adobe Muse. I have tried on multiple browsers and computers but is still the same for me.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem here? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (BTW, people around here -- including myself -- don't click through short links, anyway.)

Comment: What did you even do... I tried inspect element but wowwwww there was so much code to dig through. Learn to use classes instead of giving everything a unique ID. Don't use inline styles because it makes it very hard to dig through and identify the problem. You basically added a `position:absolute` somewhere you should not have.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The website was done on Adobe Muse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the css file:

```
html {
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

If it still doesn't work, try this:

```
html {
  overflow:scroll;
  width:110%;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: wow did you even inspect element on that site? this will not fix it. and 10 seconds to inspect element would quickly show you as well.